# What kind of points are there in a finite type $k$-scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $X$ a $k$-scheme of finite type (i.e. a scheme with a finite cover of spectra of finitely generated $k$-algebras).

> How can I think of the points $x\in X$? What does it mean intuitively for a point to be open, closed, or neither of both? What is a characterization of the points $x\in X$?

I think I found out a characterization of closed points. Please correct me, if there is something wrong.

- The *closed points* $x\in X$ can be characterized as

  - for the special case $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ exactly the maximal ideals of $A$,
  - the $x\in X$ for which the canonical morphism $\operatorname{Spec}(k(x))\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X$ is a closed immersion.
  - the $x\in X$ for which $k(x)$ is a finite field extension of $k$ (Zariki's Lemma).

My question is also about the open points $x\in X$ and the points which are neither closed nor open. I guess that a point $x\in X$ is open iff $\operatorname{Spec}(k(x))\to \operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to X$ is an open immersion.

Of course, if $X=\operatorname{Spec(A)}$ is affine, the open points $x\in X$ should be the complements of $V(I)$ containing one element for some ideal $I\subseteq A$.

Do non-closed points correspond to certain subschemes of $X$ which are in a certain sense more that zero-dimensional? If yes, what does the (transcendence) degree of the field extension $k(x)/k$ say about the point $x$ and the subscheme? How is it reflected in the subvariety if the point is open? Short: How can I think of non-closed points?

<s>I have the impression that $X$ may have at most one open point which is the (unique) generic point of $X$, if is exists, for example if $X$ is integral. Perhaps the neither closed nor open points $x\in X$ are (exactly?) the generic points of the irreducible closed subschemes of $X$ which are not $X$ itself?
What does the (transcendence) degree of the field extension $k(x)/k$ say about the point $x$? If my guess about the irreducible closed subschemes corresponding to the points was right, is this transcendence degree the Krull dimension of that subvariety?</s>

Comment: The generic point is usually not open. Think of an algebraic curve, for example.

Comment: Dear @ZhenLin, KeenanKidwell, thank you both for the clarification.

Comment: Dear @Keenan: but yes, the scheme morphism $\operatorname {Spec}(k(x))\to X$ **is** a closed immersion if $x$ is closed. Indeed it is closed, injective and $\mathcal O_{X,x}\to k(x)$ is surjective, cf. EGA I, Proposition (4.2.2.b). Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Dear @Georges, No, you're not misunderstanding me. I'm just wrong! Thank you for the correction!

Comment: Dear @jeffrey, As Georges kindly points out, my original comment was completely wrong. The morphism is a closed immersion for a closed point. My apologies!

Comment: Dear @Keenan: I'm happy to see that, once more, we are in complete agreement.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you essentially understand the situation : here is the  classification of the points of a scheme $X$ of finite type over a (completely arbitrary) field $k$.

0) The closed points are the points $x\in X$ whose residue field $\kappa(x)$ is a finite extension of $k$, i.e. $[\kappa(x):k]\lt \infty$

1) The other points $y\in Y$ correspond bijectively to the integral subschemes $Y\subset X$ of positive dimension.
In this correspondence $Y$ is the closure of $\{y\}$ and $y$ is the unique generic point of $Y$.
**Edit**  Note the subtle and potentially confusing point  that  if $X$ is irreducible but not reduced, it nevertheless has a generic point: the point  $\eta$ corresponding to the integral subscheme $X_{\operatorname {red}}\subset X$ !

2) In the above correspondence the dimension of $Y$ is equal to the transcendence degree of the extension $\kappa(y)/k$ : $$ \operatorname {dim}(Y)=\operatorname {tr.deg. } (\kappa(y)/k)             $$
3) If the scheme $X$ is connected  of positive dimension it has no open points.
The only way to obtain  open points in $X$ is to artificially take disjoint unions of schemes without open points like above with   spectra $\operatorname {Spec}(L)$ of finite extensions $L$ of $k$.
**Edit** For example for any $k$-scheme $Y$ the scheme $X=Y\sqcup \operatorname {Spec}(k)$ has $\operatorname {Spec}(k)$ as an open point.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, thank you for the clarifying answer. Does it follow from (1), that an irreducible but non-reduced $k$-scheme of finite type does not have a generic point? Concerning (2): Your answer lets me guess that open points are some trivial exceptions. I don't quite get your example of an open point. You take $X=Spec(L\times L)$ for $L$ a finite extension of $k$ and...? Thank you

Comment: Dear jeffrey: 1) Ha, but yes every irreducible scheme does have a generic point, namely the one corresponding to the integral subscheme  $Y_{\operatorname {red}}\subset Y$. This is a bit confusing and I'll write  an Edit about this. 2)  A typical scheme with open point is $X=Y\sqcup \operatorname {Spec}(k)$ where $Y$ is an arbitrary $k$-scheme .

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, thank you very much. I certainly understand the situation much better now.

Comment: Dear jeffrey, you are welcome.

Comment: Dear Georges, may I ask you which definition of a generic point you use? Is a generic point $x$ of $X$ a point with closure $\bar{\{x\}}$ equal to $X$ or is a generic point $x$ of $X$ a point such that there is an irreducible closed subscheme $Z\subseteq X$ with $\bar{ \{x\}}$ equal to $Z$? There is also a third definition: A point $x$ of $X$ is called a generic point of $X$ if $x$ is the unique point with $x\in\bar{\{x\}}$. I think the last definition is equivalent to the second, is it? Thank you.

Comment: Dear jeffrey, only the first definition is correct. Indeed, every point satisfies the second definition: this is the content of part 1) of my answer! (The third definition is the characterization of a closed point: exactly the opposite of generic...)

Comment: Dear Georges, I see that the second definition is bogus, sorry. But for the third: Liu defines in his book a generic point $x\in X$ be a unique point that specializes to $x$. Isn't this the third definition of my comment? Is it true that any irreducible scheme has exactly one generic point and there are schemes without generic points (are these exactly the non-irreducible schemes?)?

Comment: Dear jeffrey, you should now think of those matters by yourself and if you don't succeed ask a new question.